# Estimate the value as a whole number or as a mixed numeral where the fractional part is 1/2

Tags: fractions

I got into a math problem, where it asked the following question:

[image]

**I’m not asking for the answer**, but I want to know what it means by: “where the fractional part is 1/2”

Comment: Presumably it means a "*mixed numeral*" of the form $n\,\frac{1}{2}$ where $n$ is a whole number. In your case it may help to notice that $6 \lt 6\,\frac{1}{7} \lt 6\,\frac{1}{2}\,$.

Comment: @dxiv:  I think that is a good answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks. Maybe the OP will turn it into a full answer, which I'd be happy to upvote.

Comment: So.... do you think this question is asking to round $6\frac 17$ to the nearest $1/2$?

Answer (score 0):

"where the fractional part is 1/2" is referring to the mixed numeral. A *mixed numeral*, is a mix of a whole numeral and a fractional part.  In your example 6 1/7, 6 is the whole numeral and 1/7 is the fractional part.  The question is really asking you to estimate in 1/2 increments.  Is 6 1/7 closer to 6 or 6 1/2?